# how to get request["PROD_ID"] from HPP post response from realex payment

Tags: .net, global, payment-gateway, payment, realex-payments-api

I have done a post using controller to the RealexPaymentRedirectRequest
i use controller redirect request post to realex payments.

```
RedirectRequest postData = new RealexPaymentRedirectRequest()
                                        {
                                            Account = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexaccount", "internet"),
                                            AutoSettleFlag = "1",
                                            Currency = "GBP",
                                            MerchantId = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexmerchant", "merchant"),
                                            MerchantResponseUrl = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexmerchantResponseUrl", "http://www.mydomainhost.uk/service/CompletePayment.ashx"),
                                            OrderId = orderId,
                                            Timestamp = RealexPaymentRedirectRequest.GenerateTimestamp(),
                                            Secret = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexsecret", "topsceret"),

                                            Vat = vatRate != 0 ? vatRate : Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetIntSetting("realexdefaultVatRate", 20),
                                            Amount = amountToPay,
                                            ProdId = prodId
                                        };
```

I would like to get the prod id string back to my confirmation page.
I have tried from HPP response request  using request[PROD_ID],
but this is returning empty string.

Comment: Not really an expert on RealexPaymentRedirectRequest, but could the value that you are looking for hiding in another form collection key?

Comment: The response from the HPP post contains these are the fields.https://developer.globalpay.com/#!/hpp/payment-methods#hpp-return-url

Comment: I need prod_id to return from HPP response post